# Java swing jpanel dimension

Tags: java, swing

[image]

```
    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JLabel descLabel = new JLabel("<html>description");
    descLabel.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    descLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    add(descLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Home.class.getResource("/icon/img.jpg")));
    picLabel.setIconTextGap(-310);
    picLabel.setOpaque(true);
    picLabel.setLayout(null);
    add(picLabel);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, true));
    JButton btnDetails = new JButton("Dettagli");
    JButton btnDetails2 = new JButton("Modifica");
    buttonPanel.add(btnDetails);
    buttonPanel.add(btnDetails2);
    add(buttonPanel);
```

I want to change the dimension of the panel (see the image) and align it with the image.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: please share at least the code of all components added to your main panel. Which layout is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the layout of your main panel to use `BorderLayout`.

Then add the `picLabel` to be `add(picLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER)` and your buttonPanel as `add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH)` and you should get better layout.

Packing the dialog / frame will also help.

You **cannot** add two labels to the same position in a BorderLayout. Your label `descLabel` will **replace** your `titleLabel`

You could do that like the buttons: Create another panel, add both labels vertically and add that to your main panel with `BorderLayout.NORTH` (or PAGE_START)

Comment: i have also two label but it appears only one..
`JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title, SwingConstants.CENTER);
       titleLabel.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
       titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 15));
       add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);`

Comment: can you edit your question and show new code with ALL lables and Layout set?

Comment: how i add the labels vertically?

Comment: use another BorderLayout on new Panel and add one label BorderLayout.NORTH and the other BorderLayout.SOUTH for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99707/discussion-between-fr4ncx-and-jan).